# LINQ Where Count Check

Tags: linq, count, group-by, where-clause

So I'm slowly getting my head around the LINQ syntax, but this query's driving me nuts..

I only want to return filters with more than one filter value.. I've tried putting a group by on fv but p goes out of scope then..

```
        var filters = (from p in _db.Products
                  join pf in _db.ProductFilterSets on p.ProductID equals pf.ProductID
                  join fv in _db.FilterValues on pf.FilterValueID equals fv.FilterValueID
                  join f in _db.Filters on fv.FilterID equals f.FilterID
                  where products.Contains(p) 
                  select f).Distinct();
```

What am I doing wrong?

I ideally need:

```
        var filters = (from p in _db.Products
                  join pf in _db.ProductFilterSets on p.ProductID equals pf.ProductID
                  join fv in _db.FilterValues on pf.FilterValueID equals fv.FilterValueID
                  join f in _db.Filters on fv.FilterID equals f.FilterID
                  where products.Contains(p) && fv.Count() > 1
                  select f).Distinct();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the query like this, adding another join on the _db.FilterValues but projecting the result to a group by using the `into` keyword

```
var filters = (from p in _db.Products
               join pf in _db.ProductFilterSets on p.ProductID equals pf.ProductID
               join fv in _db.FilterValues on pf.FilterValueID equals fv.FilterValueID into fvg
               join fv in _db.FilterValues on pf.FilterValueID equals fv.FilterValueID
               join f in _db.Filters on fv.FilterID equals f.FilterID
               where products.Contains(p) && fvg.Count() > 1
               select f).Distinct();
```

Comment: Cheers, this ought to work a charm. Compiles just fine however i'm not getting any data back at all now though, need to check elsewhere for errors.. Will update again, thank you I never thought to join again into a group :)